# Any other tools like Inctrl5 out there?

Tags: windows, installation

I've been using InControl5 for 10+ years to take snapshots of Windows folders and registry while testing software installation packages.  It takes a snapshot of the system before running the install program and then takes another snapshot when the install is complete.  It compares the two snapshots and generates a report which shows files, folders and registry values created, modified or deleted.

It seems to me there might be a newer/better tool out there by now.  Does anyone use anything else for this kind of purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [Sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com/) combined with an additional utility called [SandboxDiff](https://vetusware.com/download/SandboxDiff%202.3%20PT/?id=16918) that might be able to do what you need. The author of SandboxDiff mentioned he had also previously used InControl5.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [RegShot](http://regshot.sourceforge.net/) !

> "Regshot is an open-source (LGPL) registry compare utility that allows
>   you to quickly take a snapshot of your registry and then compare it
>   with a second one - done after doing system changes or installing a
>   new software product."

Comment: I gave it a go, and although the UI is rather minimalistic, it does its job. The report actually looks rather fine - and having it as an open source could mean it will remain relevant and non-bloat. Thanks

Comment: I think NirSoft Registry Changes View is worth a look as it can export directly to a `.reg` file format, making it much easier to check what happened, clean up the `.reg` file and apply it again on another system.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look at [Total Uninstall](http://www.martau.com/). I've been using it for years and it's a very efficient uninstaller that compares snapshots before and after installation. Very reliable and highly configurable.

Comment: Note: their trial is restricted, it's not the Pro version. Means one cannot do comparisons or run it in a virtual machine. Obviously, such trial policy harms them themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Well PC Magazine has updated InCtrl5 itself, but since they started charging for utilities several years ago, InCtrlX is not free.

An alternate programs is [ZSoft Uninstaller](http://www.zsoft.dk/index/software_details/4). I’ve tried a lot of these kinds of programs and ZSoft’s was the next best one to InCtrl; it works pretty well, is fairly effective at catching changes to both the file-system and registry without cluttering with too many false-positives, and unlike most programs in the category is actually free.